# Opus Audio Codec issues when paired with Bluetooth

Tags: android, audio, discord, bluetooth, codec

I do not have a direct code example for this, this is simply the last place I know where to go with this.

Whenever I talk to a friend on Discord, while they use their Phone and Bluetooth-Headphones, they sound super muffled, and so do I for them.
It is 100% not my fault, as I use a PC Setup with a proper Mic and Headphones.

We have tried virtually everything,the Bluetooth Codec itself sounds fine (SBC, Mic tested on Audio Recorder, playback tested with an MP3, both sound crystal clear), any other Audio Codecs (alaw, tested over normal call, together with SBC sounds perfectly fine)

As soon as we use the Bluetooth Headphones with any Bluetooth Codec and the Opus Audio Codec (tested on Discord and Messenger), it sounds absolutely terrible. The second they Disconnect the Headphones and use their normal built-in mic, so the Bluetooth codec gets dropped, it sounds perfectly fine again.

So just using a Bluetooth Codec OR the Opus Codec sounds fine, but as soon as you combine any Bluetooth codec with the Opus Codec, it sounds horrendous.

Now to the ultra weird part. As soon as they talk to someone in their House over Discord, so same audio codec, same BT codec, THE SOUND IS PERFECTLY FINE.

I am at a complete loss. My Audio knowledge ends at some googling.
Can anyone nudge me into a direction what this could be? I am loosing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in Bluetooth Audio. When microphone is not used, the headphones use A2DP profile that supports modern codecs and higher bitrates. But when the microphone is enabled, the headphones switch into legacy HSP profile that does not support neither good codecs nor high bitrates.

Bluetooth LE Audio with LC3 codec should fix this when it becomes supported everywhere.